# Unable to Select options from dropdown field?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

I'm using Selenium-webdriver with *Java* from the *MavenProject*. Version *2.53.0.*

This is the HTML of the dropdown field:

```
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7">
  <select id="user_contract_type_of_contract" name="user_contract[type_of_contract]" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="780">N/A</option>
    <option value="775">Contract onbepaalde duur</option>
    <option value="774">Contract bepaalde duur</option>
    <option value="778">Interim</option>
    <option value="776">IBO</option>
    <option value="777">Industrieel leerling</option>
    <option value="781">Stagiair</option>
    <option value="779">Jobstudent</option>
    <option value="782">Vervangingscontract</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I'm trying to select the second option from the field named '**Contract onbepaalde duur**'.
I've tried 2 things so far, neither worked:

**Attempt 1**:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("user_contract_type_of_contract")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000); // I wait here just to play it safe
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"user_contract_type_of_contract\"]/option[2]")).click();
```

**Attempt 2**:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("user_contract_type_of_contract")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000); // I wait here just to play it safe
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Contract onbepaalde duur']")).click();
```

**Current output**:

What both attempts do is, they click on the field. The dropdown opens and it waits a few seconds it selects the second option but somehow it doesn't seem to click the option (it **does get selected**) but then it hops to the next field to fill that one in. BUT instead of saving the selected field it saves the first default option '**N/A**'.

**Question**:

What am I doing wrong that it doesn't save the selected/clicked item?

Comment: select option is not working on div elements. Error Message : "selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **Select** method in WebDriver-

```
WebElement contractType = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='user_contract_type_of_contract']"));

Select dropdownField = new Select(contractType);
dropdownField.selectByVisibleText("Contract onbepaalde duur");

OR
// Select by using index starting from 0 to ...you have to select 2nd option so take as index-1
dropdownField.selectByindex(1);
```

Comment: use different xpath-as- By.xpath (//*[@id='user_contract_type_of_contract']")

I think it w'll definitely works,- if it is not works let me know-
Always try to avoid  "Thread.sleep" 
Use implicitly wait instead of this

Comment: Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You can also select dropdown option by value

```
WebElement userContractType = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='user_contract_type_of_contract']"));

Select selectValue = new Select(userContractType);
selectValue.selectByValue("775");
```

Comment: Why not use By Id?

Comment: You can use By Id also, for some case Id is not available so using xpath is right option.